# SAS assign results from macro function to array within data step

Tags: macros, sas

This code takes two macros and assigns them to arrays inside a data step, then loops through each variable defined in ln_vars, creating a new variable which is the natural log of the variable, appending _ln to the name

```
%let ln_vars = var1 var2;
%let ln_names = %add_string(&ln_vars, _ln);

data transform;
    set analysis;
    array ln &ln_vars;
    array ln_n &ln_names;
    *call execute ('%add_string(%str(&ln_vars), _ln)');

do over ln;
    ln_n = log(ln);
end;

run;
```

maybe there's a better idiom in sas code (I hope).
I want to be able to just pass a single macro (the ln_vars macro) and call the %add_string() function from inside the data step. 
The commented 'call execute' returns the correct string, but when I try to

```
1588       array ln_n call execute ('%add_string(%str(&ln_vars), _ln)');
ERROR: Attempt to initialize variable call in numeric array ln_n with character constant
       '%add_string(%str(&ln_vars), _ln)'.
```

Comment: Before you try to automate, write code that executes successfully for one observation in analysis. Post that code (and sample data) and it will be easier to help.

Comment: the code above works.  I want to replace &ln_names in the data step with some version of the call execute command commented out below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you gave us the definition of the %add_string macro. In any case, it looks like you need &ln_names to be a list of variables matching the list in &ln_vars except each variable has the suffix '_ln'.

If I'm correct, you don't really need the %add_string macro and could do this instead:

```
%let ln_vars = var1 var2;
%let ln_names = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&ln_vars,%str( ),%str(_ln )))_ln;
%put LN_VARS: &ln_vars;
%put LN_NAMES:&ln_names;

data transform;
  set analysis;
  array ln &ln_vars;
  array ln_n &ln_names;
  do over ln;
    ln_n = log(ln);
  end;
run;
```

Note that the two %put statements are not really necessary - they are just placed there to inspect the values of the two macro variables

---

As per your comment, you could have a macro:

```
%macro lnvars(vars=,suffix=_ln);

  %let newvars=%sysfunc(tranwrd(&vars,%str( ),%str(&suffix )))&suffix;

  array ln &vars.;
  array ln_n &newvars.;
  do over ln;
    ln_n = log(ln);
  end;

%mend;
```

and then call the macro from your data step as follows:

```
data transform;
  set analysis;
  %lnvars(vars=var1 var2);
run;
```

(Note, I've not tested the code, but you should get the general idea)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid passing two macro variables into the data step.

Comment: See the alternative. You're still referencing a macro we cannot see, i.e. %add_string.